# -webkit-background-clip not working in Safari

Tags: html, css

The code below works on Chrome but not on Safari. I cannot work out why, so any help would be greatly appreciated. A live demo can be found at https://jacobcxdev.me/beta/ (while the problem persists). A screen recording can be found [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/244242279865384963/546790404603773020/whai.mov).

CSS:

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
}

.button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  font-size: 4vmin;
  font-weight: 100;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  transition: box-shadow, background-color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow, background-color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.button:hover {
  transition: box-shadow, background-color, text-shadow, color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow, background-color, text-shadow, color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  text-shadow: none;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .button:hover {
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-color: black;
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -5px white, inset 0px 0px 200px -50px white;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button class="button" onclick="location.href='about/'">About me</button>
</body>

<!--hover to view text-->
```

Comment: I actually think it's the transition rather than the background-clip that is causing the issue. See the [note on caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=transition-timing) regarding Safari 11 and transitions. I removed the transition effects from the class button (not the hover class) and it made a difference. https://jsbin.com/yofiyaluli/

Comment: @RachelGallen That's odd as that jsbin doesn't work for me on Safari. It does work on Chrome but not using Safari.

Comment: Maybe it's your version of safari. IF possible, upgrade it.

Comment: @RachelGallen I believe I'm on the latest available. It also occurs on iOS 12 with both Chrome and Safari, so it's an issue with Webkit's compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the color "transparent" on hover is being treated differently between browsers.  You can change your CSS to pick the color you intend the text to be and this will work for Chrome and Safari.

```
@media (hover: hover) {
    .button:hover {
        background-clip: text;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-color: black;
        color: black; /* change this color */
        text-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px -5px white, inset 0px 0px 200px -50px white;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that almost works, though it doesn't produce the cut-out effect as with Chrome, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please explain “cut out effect” and I will take another look.

Comment: If you look at the website on Chrome and hover over the button, you will see that the text appears to be "cut out" from the box-shadow, and so displays a bit of a gradient, while still being readable and looking great.